# Compare files in VSCode and output the differences automatically to a separate file

Tags: bash, visual-studio-code, automation, diff

I use VSCode to compare 2 large csv files (each is almost 140k lines).. I have used `>compare active file with..`

I want to extract only the difference to clean it up manually.

How can I do that?

Is there any extension or tip will help me on this?

Comment: what do you want to do after cleaning up the differences in the diff file

Comment: It will be easier for me to deal with (only the differences) in one file. some changes I will keep them, and some I will restore them back

Comment: then use a merge tool, like WinMerge, how are you going the edit the difference file so it can be applied with `git patch`

Comment: thanks, @rioV8 for your answer. I am using mac OS. could you please suggest a suitable tool for mac users?

Comment: I don't use Mac, do a web search

Comment: Could you post a simple example (< 10 lines) of your inputs and the expected output ?

Comment: I found this https://www.scootersoftware.com/ which seems good. thanks